# TortoiseSVN Join multiple files into one

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to join multiple files into one.
I have units Unit1.pas, Unit2.pas, Unit3.pas and I am replacing them with new Unit4.pas. Unit4.pas is completely replaces old files functionality, does not share old code.
In future, when viewing Unit4.pas SVN log, I want to see it replaced Unit1.pas, Unit2.pas and Unit3.pas.
How to do this?

Comment: Subversion itself doesn't support that history flow, so neither does TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to merge unrelated files. Rename one of the files to Unit4.pas, change its contents, and delete the other two.